# How to update database values of existing entites that have the "Init" accessor in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, immutability, c#-9.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a class that has a property whose "Set" accessor is "Init". I believe this means this value can only be set during initialization/construction of the object (via the constructor or via object initializer). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init

With regards to immutabilty, this works perfectly because when I create an instance of this class, I am unable to mutate the value of that property after is has been initialized.

However when I get that object from the database and wish to update the value,  I am unable to edit the value (which is entirely what I expect).

I get that once it has been initialized I am unable to mutate it, but is there a way in entity framework core to update the value during construction or initialization? Or am I able to just update the property of that entity with our loading the object from the database.

Surely there is a way to leverage the init accessor whilst still being able to update values in the database?

Comment: So you want to be able to initialize it only where constructed - except when it comes from the database? Does not sound like an ideal candidate for `init`.

Comment: I actually don't even want to load it from the database. I only want to update it.

Comment: So you have an entity that you want to `new` with an ID and another property, and attach that so EF sends an update query? Some relevant code would help